GnuPG: is it possible to sign a precreated digest/hash?
With gpg -s <input file> will create the hash of the file and sign it.
Is there an option to let the caller prepare the hash and let gpg just sign the hash provided?

--detach-sign will store the signature into a separate file, but as far as I understand as input it still await a file that it will hash itself.
